# To Create a Function to split dates into Year, Month, Date into a separate column in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to create a function to split dateformat of "2018-05-21" to 2018 | 05 | 21 | as three separate columns. Tried creating the function as below but gives me error on "month", "Day". Error says "incorrect syntax near 'month'. Expecting '(' or Select."

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[functionname]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @DateFormat AS DATETIME
)
RETURNS VARCHAR (MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN  DATEPART(YEAR,@DateFormat),
                DATEPART(Month,@DateFormat),
                DATEPART(Day,@DateFormat)

    END
GO
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a function for this?

Comment: So that others can also call it, when they want to use it directly on any kind of analysis o have a better format to use.

Comment: I did try this on table directly. It does work.
   /*  DATEPART(year,Date) as year,
   DATEPART(month,Date) as Month,
   DATEPART(DD,Date)as Date */

Comment: I don't want to give this every-time on a table to get the required format rather use a function.

Comment: If you already have the date formatted with -  you can do a replace(date, '-', '|')

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get exactly what you want. A Table-valued function may be your closest match.

Comment: I want them as separate columns.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn > So i won't be able to create separate columns using functions?

Comment: Probably not in the way you want, that can be used on individual rows in a select query... That cross apply answer might get the job done, but anyone who can write an APPLY statement also knows how to call MONTH() if they need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current SQL is that a scalar only returns a single value. You need to use a table value function to get multiple columns.

This is a TVF version which will provide three columns

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionName]
(
    @DateFormat AS DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,@DateFormat) AS [Year],
       DATEPART(Month,@DateFormat) AS [Month],
       DATEPART(Day,@DateFormat) AS [Day]
)
```

Example usage:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (SomeDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @dates SELECT '01/25/2018'
INSERT INTO @dates SELECT '10/01/2008'

SELECT d.*,fn.* FROM @dates d
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[FunctionName](d.SomeDate) fn
```

And some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

That said, I personally don't like this implementation. I would simply expect the DATEPART statements in the SELECT portion of the SQL. I think the TVF makes it more complicated and doesn't provide any tangible benefits.

Comment: Beat me to it! But there it is. <Clearing my clipboard>

Comment: Perfect! This worked. I have a question. If is select certain columns to be viewed and apply TVF, i dont see the o/p except for the selected columns in the select statement. For example, if i give
SELECT Column1,Column2, Column3 from [Tablename] CROSS APPLY [dbo].[FunctionName](columnname)

Comment: @Tamil Add an alias to the function call and you can specify the alias.column field you want. I've updated my example to show this.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Thank you!! Works perfect!!